# How can I hide one field of an HTML form?

Tags: html, forms

I have a simple HTML form that I'm using to drive site search for a website I'm creating.

Two of the fields should not be used together, such as "make" and "model" of a car. You wouldn't want someone searching for a "Ford Ram Truck," for instance.

How can I modify my form so that if a certain value in one of the fields is selected, the other field disappears?

Thank you for your help!

```
<select name="make">
  <option value="item 1">item 1</option>
  <option value="item 2">item 2</option>
</select>

<select name="model">
  <option value="item 1">item 1</option>
  <option value="item 2">item 2</option>
</select>

<input name="" type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use javascript and hook up to the change event of the radio buttons.

In your javascript you can set the visibility of any form element to hidden or visible (depending on which you want).

You would still need to validate/check on the server side in order to avoid such a search (since javascript may be off or a malicious user might override your client side validation).

Answer (score 0):

I think [Chained Select Menu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/chainedmenu/chainedmenu.html) can solve your problem.